# Has the Marvel Universe ever crossed over with DC Universe?

Tags: marvel, dc

Has the Marvel Universe ever crossed over with DC Universe in any books, comics, cartoons or movies?

I mean did any character or event, maybe idea or location slip from one universe to the other?

I often see art where DC characters fight, talk, drink, play, etc. with characters from Marvel.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate - oh wait!?

Comment: Why all the unexplained downvotes?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" seems to be a good explanation for the downvotes, though none of them are mine.

Comment: See also this thread and especially post # 40.  https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/star-trek-is-part-of-mcu.293148/page-2

Answer (score 5):

There are at least 16 cases of Marvel/DC crossover, beginning with “Superman vs. The Amazing Spider-Man” in 1976. Other teamups include Spider-Man & Batman, X-Men & Teen Titans, Daredevil & Batman, and JLA & Avengers. You can see a list [here](https://www.cbr.com/marvel-and-dc-16-times-their-heroes-teamed-up/).
In addition, the two companies have often spoofed and 'borrowed' from each other. Marvel introduced the Squadron Sinister as a thiny veiled, villanous version of Justice League. Squadron Sinister later got a good, parallel universe version called Squadron Supreme. The first version of the Shi'ar Imperial Guard had quite a lot in common with DC's Legion of Super-Heroes (probably because the X-Men artist at the time, Dave Cockrum, had drawn LSH for years). DC's General Glory was, in return, originally a spoof on Captain America. There are probably many more such examples.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for the marvel parallel universe known as [Earth-7642](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-7642)

> In this universe, Marvel and DC characters coexist with one another. It also includes characters from other franchises, such as the Transformers, WildC.A.T.s, Witchblade, and Shi.